# Saving my csv output into file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new to python and would like to learn data sets, I have following script to load and manipulate my csv file

```
# import pandas with shortcut 'pd'
import pandas as pd
  
# read_csv function which is used to read the required CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('data/dummy-data-export-large.csv')
  
# display
print("Original CSV Data: \n")
print(data)
  
# pop function which is used in removing or deleting columns from the CSV files
data.pop('Order ID')
data.pop('Day')
data.pop('Month')
data.pop('Year')
data.pop('Product ID')
data.pop('Product Tag')
data.pop('Sales Person')
data.pop('Main Ingredient')
data.pop('Product')
data.pop('Price')
  
# display
print("\nCSV Data after deleting the columns:\n")
print(data)
```

Rather than printing the data I would like to be able to save into (new) csv file.

Many thanks, T

Being able to save into file

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `to_csv()` method on the DataFrame for writing a CSV to disk:

```py
data.to_csv("my_file_name.csv")
```

Check the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to get information about arguments that can be used with that method.

Also, you should not use `.pop()` if you not want to make further use of the column, as `.pop()` returns the item after dropping.

To drop columns, better use the [drop()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) method which enables you to drop multiple columns at once and will also be computationally cheaper:

```py
data = data.drop(['Order ID', 'Day', 'Month'], axis=1)
```

or

```py
data.drop(['Order ID', 'Day', 'Month'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```